# What is wrong with my code in finding the length of Maximum Bitonic Subarray

Tags: c++

Logic used is simple if a triplet x,y,z occurs such that x>y<z then give the length of the array to m and continue and it gives right output in all the test cases I can think of

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
 int t;
 cin>>t;
 while(t--)
 {
     int n;
     cin>>n;
     int a[n];
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
      cin>>a[i];
     }
     int l=0;
     int m=0;
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         l++;
         if(i>0&&i<n-1)
         {
         if(a[i]<a[i-1]&&a[i]<a[i+1])
         {
             l=1;
         }
         }
         if(m<l)
         m=l;
     }
     if(m)
     cout<<m<<endl;
     else 
     cout<<l<<endl;
 }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int n; int a[n];` is not valid c++. Use a vector instead.

Comment: A MBS can also start as `x < y > z` too apart from `x > y < z`. That's the case you missed out on.